# Git Dealing with merge conflict with tracked and untracked files

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I am in this `develop` branch and i checkout to new local branch to develop new feature.

```
git checkout -b task-change-title-and-styling
```

Then now i do some code changes and now i have both `tracked` and `untrack` files.

My common practices where i know there wouldn't be a merge conflict are as following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Change titles and styling on homepage"
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/develop
git push -u origin task-change-title-and-styling
```

Done.

Now in new situation where i know my changes will conflict with other, what should i do (assume that i have both `tracked` and `untracked` files)?

Following is just my assumption to deal with merge conflict, but not sure whether the steps are correct

```
git add .
git commit -m "Change titles and styling on homepage"
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/develop

*at this point i assume my git will have merge conflict message*
```

Then i fix my merge conflicts, then i do

```
git add .
git rebase --continue
*there are still conflict message*
```

Fix my codes again, then do

```
git add .
git rebase --continue
*now no more merge conflict message*
git push -u origin task-change-title-and-styling
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.
Although, I never use git fetch origin before rebase, because git rebase origin/develop already does pulling of the newest version of develop branch.

Comment: ic, after fix the conflicts, should i `git add .` then only `git rebase --continue` or i should just `git rebase --continue` without the `add` part?

Comment: Yes you should do git add . after solving conflicts. But, if you use WebStorm as texteditor and for solving conflicts, he does that for you.